# "Cannot Resolve Symbol" error using a public class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have 1 activity and 1 fragment involved on this one.
In the fragment I declare the public class FetchWeatherTask:

```
    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null){
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for(String dayForecastStr : result)
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
        }





        //region JSON PARSING SNIPPET
        //*****************************************************************************************************************************


        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
 * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
 */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {


            String unitType = prefs.getString(
                    getString(R.string.pref_default_unit_key),
                    getString(R.string.pref_default_temp));






            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast Entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;
        }


        //endregion


        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(params.length == 0)
                return null;

            //region HTTPConnection Snippet
            // **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************


            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;



            String format ="json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;
            String apiKey ="b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a";



            try {

                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast

                //region URI_BUILDER
                //***********************************************************************************************************************
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM ="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
                final String API_KEY_PARAM="appid";

                Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY_PARAM,apiKey).build();

                //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "BuiltURI: " + buildUri.toString());

                URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());

                //endregion



                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                //(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " + forecastJsonStr);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            //endregion

            try{
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;
        }


    }
```

This class is then instanciated in the MainActivity in the method onOptionsItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_default_location));


        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute(location);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The IDE suggest a change in the declaration of the weatherTaks by making it static. This does resolve the error on this method, although I am not able to use some other methods like:

```
String unitType = prefs.getString(
```

getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));

the inner getString will say "cannot use non-static methods on static methods" (i dont record the exact words but it was what it meant)

Resuming to the main objective: How can I use the public class in another activity, even though it's marked public and I even imported my package which is:

```
import com.example.diomonogatarilaptop.sunshine.MainActivityFragment;
```

Thank you for reading

EDIT: Fragment code

```
package com.example.diomonogatarilaptop.sunshine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {



    public final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }


    private void updateWeather(){
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                        getString(R.string.pref_default_location));
        weatherTask.execute(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        updateWeather();
    }


    //region AsyncTask Weather Fetcher
    //********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null){
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for(String dayForecastStr : result)
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
        }





        //region JSON PARSING SNIPPET
        //*****************************************************************************************************************************


        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
 * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
 */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {


            String unitType = prefs.getString(
                    getString(R.string.pref_default_unit_key),
                    getString(R.string.pref_default_temp));






            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast Entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;
        }


        //endregion


        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(params.length == 0)
                return null;

            //region HTTPConnection Snippet
            // **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************


            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;



            String format ="json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;
            String apiKey ="b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a";



            try {

                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast

                //region URI_BUILDER
                //***********************************************************************************************************************
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM ="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
                final String API_KEY_PARAM="appid";

                Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY_PARAM,apiKey).build();

                //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "BuiltURI: " + buildUri.toString());

                URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());

                //endregion



                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                //(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " + forecastJsonStr);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            //endregion

            try{
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;
        }


    }
    //endregion
    //region onCreateView
    //***********************************************************************************************************************************
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);



        //region Where the data is







        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                new ArrayList<String>());

        ListView lista = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        lista.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


        //region onClickListener manda tostas
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //endregion
        //endregion





















        return rootView;




    }
    //endregion






}
```

Comment: you can't call a non-static method in a static context, is that the error message you get?

Comment: @Stultuske exactly :)

Comment: @Stultuske Try to be constructive, please

Comment: Can you please show the Fragment code? I don't see how that error exists with the code that is shown.

Comment: @cricket_007 how is encouraging people to work with material they can never totally understand because they don't understand the basics on which it is built constructive?

Comment: @Stultuske I dont exactly understand how to apply the last part to solving the question, sry.
I've been "forced" to transition from c# to android studio, so yea I lack the java fundamentals.

Comment: @cricket_007 i've edited the question with the fragment code

Comment: Somewhere you are calling an instance member (beit a method or a variable) through the classname. instance members are directly linked to an instance of the class (for instance, every Person has it's own (unique) name). Person.getName() makes no sense, since for the abstract Person, name doesn't exist. Jeff.getName() (through instance Jeff) does make sense.

Comment: Its because you are instantiating an Inner class without instantiating the outer class

Comment: @Stultuske I'm instanciating my public class and giving the name weatherTask, where I want to execute my method, .execute
I have to use the default constructor to call it, because i didnt define a new constructor.
I'm not calling a method from a class, im calling a method from the instance of a class

Comment: true, but that's not what that error message is complaining about. You can call a static method through an instance. (it's pointless but valid and possible). it's the other way around that doesn't work. Which line of your code causes this issue?

Comment: @Stultuske, FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute(location);
        return true;
on the onOptionsItemSelected, I can't make an instance

Comment: its because it is inside MainFragment, you need to have instance of mainfragment only then you can instantiate any inner class in MainFragment.  
You should move FetchWeatherTask outside MainFragment, as it is a helper or util class

Comment: @RavjitSingh, I've tried that before, it says that "is not an enclosing class

Comment: Can you post how you did it? 
It should give that error if you do **new MainFragment.FetchWeatherTask()** but not if you do **new MainFragment. new FetchWeatherTask()**
This is anyways not right architecturally.
In MainActivity you might have a reference to MainFragment (lets say its **mainFragment**) then you should call **mainFragment. new FetchWeatherTask()**

Comment: @RavjitSingh, I'm doing it like this `MainActivityFragment.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new MainActivityFragment.FetchWeatherTask();`
I'm moving this class out of the fragment to a class of his own, if that doesnt work I commit **sudoku**

Comment: @diomonogatari it's exactly what I told you, read my previous comment. It would work, currently you are still creating an instance of FetchWeatherTask, you never instantiated MainActivityFragment. 
Do this please **new MainFragment(). new FetchWeatherTask()**

Comment: @RavjitSingh wow it worked as a charm thank you

Comment: @diomonogatari it works but I hope you are not making a new instance of MainFragment everytime, try to reuse already created instance of MainFragment!
Cheers

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but until you understand some more Java fundamentals, I would suggest making separate Java files for all your different classes.

Comment: Ty @cricket_007 for your suggestion, I will do, it makes it more code clean too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are trying to instantiate an inner class without a reference to an instance to the outer class. You should do,

```
new MainFragment(). new FetchWeatherTask();
```

But probably you already created an instance of MainFragment(let's say its mainFragment) then you should just use this:

```
mainFragment. new FetchWeatherTask();
```